# Bootstrap col-md becomes larger because of absolute position of div inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, navbar

I have problem with the absolute positioning of Logo image in the nav.

My logo must be half on the navbar and half bellow.

When I add a class inside col-md-3 with te property position: absolute the size of the parent col-md-3 becomes larger than normal col-md-3.

This is how it should look:

[image: scheme]

For better positiong of the content I pulled the nav and logo in one row and two cols (col-md-2 and col-md-10). The conntent bellow the first row is one row with two cols - col-md-offset-2 col-md-7 and col-md-3. The cols ow both rows must have the same witdh.

The code:
http://www.bootply.com/VJYSA55MEt

My question is why the logo col-md-3 is bigger then the col-md-3 in the second row. Both cols must have the same width...i don't know how to fix the width...

Or have you a better way to handle this (primary, that the logo is on and bellow the navbar, and that the content bellow the navbar begins right to the logo)

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to know? And, how about a tableless design? [W3C](https://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto) shows how to do it and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461103/why-is-the-bootstrap-grid-layout-preferable-to-an-html-table) explains why you should go for tableless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use [default layout](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default). If you increase the height of the logo, it comes out of the navbar. This is its peculiarity. Typically this becomes a problem. But now this is the way to solve your task.

Please check the result.

http://www.bootply.com/u2QhCYtrQ3

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar > .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    width: 16.66666667%; /* width of .col-md-2 */
  }
  .navbar-header img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

section .row { margin-bottom: 50px; }
section .row > div > div { height: 50px; }
.green  { background: green;  }
.blue   { background: blue;   }
.red    { background: red;    }
.silver { background: silver; }
```

```html
<header class="header-main">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top nav-izbornik"   role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Test centar">  
          <img src="//dummyimage.com/225x200/000/fff" alt="" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm logo-borderi">
          <img src="//dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="" class="hidden-md hidden-lg logo-za-manje">
        </a>        
      </div><!--.navbar-header-->    
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 02</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 04</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
        </ul>      
      </div><!--nav-collapse -->    
    </div><!--container-->
  </nav>  
</header>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7"><div class="red"></div></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><div class="blue"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"><div class="silver"></div></div>
      <div class="col-md-10"><div class="green"></div></div>
    </div>
  </div><!--container-->
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use col-md in Absolute div. Use Absolute in logo And Relative in Nav Then Give some Top value it will came down. like

```
.logo{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
}
.nav{
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Also give left value If need.

Comment: How can I be sure that my logo and divs under it and right of it will have the same width if I dont use col - md

Comment: use width height for your logo. And give a z-index value in logo for keen it front

Comment: I know that I can fix that with adding height and width, but it's more complicated to adjust the dimensions for smaller divices.

I think that is way batter to add the logo in col-md-3, and add img-responsive class to the logo so, the height and width are adjusts auto

it's important that the logo div is the same width as the div under it...therefore i want use col-md-3. to prevent diferent sizes.

Comment: use height width by % than it will be responsive

Comment: Thats correct, but it remains to adjust the width so the logo fits the width of the col-md-3 under itd. I want the exact this http://www.imagebam.com/image/c78bce489244241